# Why does this inheritance hierarchy not permit this assignment?

Tags: inheritance, c#-4.0, covariance

I have the following complex inheritance hierarchy:

```
I1<I3>
A1 : C1, I2
C2 : A1, I3
C3 : A2<C2>, I4                
A2<C2> : I5, I1<C2>
```

In picture form:

[image: Inheritance diagram]

Writing:

```
I1<I3> i = new C3();
```

...results in the compilation error "Cannot convert source type... to target type...".

Why?

Comment: I3 is not a type and therefore cannot be used as a generic type?

Comment: I3 is an interface. C2 implements I3, and therefore is covariant. C3 implements I1<C2>, which through covariance is also I1<I3>. Therefore I should be able to write the line in the question? Clearly I have a misunderstanding...

Answer (score 0):

Covariant and contravariant generic parameters should be explicitly marked as such.

The following code compiles without error (note the **out** keyword):

```
class tmp
{
    class C1 {}
    interface I2 {}
    interface I3 {}
    interface I4 {}
    interface I5 {}
    interface I1<out I3> {}
    class A1 : C1, I2 {}
    class C2 : A1, I3 {}
    class C3 : A2<C2>, I4 {}
    class A2<C2> : I5, I1<C2> { }

    private void Main()
    {
        I1<I3> i = new C3();
    }
}
```

Of course, without the **out** keyword it fails with the same error message as you described.